# Minimum no. of generators over local rings having a ring homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\phi : (R, \mathfrak{m}) \rightarrow (S,\mathfrak{n})$ be a local ring map and $M$ be an $S$ module and $R$ module via the ring map $\phi.$

Does there always exist a nonzero module $M$ such that the cardinality of the minimal no. of generator of $M$ over $S$ and over $R$ are different?

i.e. $$ \mu_R(M) \neq \mu_S(M).$$

I am looking for such a module(possibly an ideal) over the ring map
$$ \phi \colon \frac{Q[x,y,z]}{(x^3,y^2,z^4)} \rightarrow \frac{Q[x,y,z]}{(x^3,y^2,z^4,x^2 y z^3)}.$$

Comment: If $\phi$ is surjective, then $\mu_R(M)$ equals $\mu_R(M)$ for every $S$-module $M$ since a generating set for $M$ as an $S$-module is the same thing as a generating set for $M$ as an $R$-module.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but conversely to Jason's comment, if $\phi$ is not surjective, then $\mu_R(S)>1$ but $\mu_S(S)=1$, so does the nonzero module $S$ work?